# Including a self signed keystore to list of trusted certificates

Tags: java, pdf, itext, bouncycastle

Using the following command ;

keytool -keystore org726.store -genkey -alias org726

The password i used for above steps was "password". Its hardcoded in the code underneath in ks.load().

i am generating the keystore and using a java program to digitally sign the pdf

```
public void signPdfFirstTime(String src, String dest)
{
    try{
    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
 Security.addProvider(provider);
 //KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
String path = properties.getProperty("PRIVATE");
String keystore_password = properties.getProperty("PASSWORD");
String PASSWORD = "password";
 ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE1), PASSWORD.toCharArray());
 //ks.load(new FileInputStream(path), keystore_password.toCharArray());
 String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
 PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, "password".toCharArray());
 Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
       FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
       PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
       // appearance
       PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper .getSignatureAppearance();
      appearance.setImage(Image.getInstance("D:\\logo.jpg"));
       appearance.setReason("I've written this.");
       appearance.setLocation("Chennai");
       appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(72, 732, 144, 780), 1,    "first");
       // digital signature
   System.out.println(PageSize.A4.getHeight());
   System.out.println(PageSize.A4.getWidth());
       ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1, provider.getName());
       ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
       MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But in the resultant pdf i am getting:
Signer's identity is unknown because it has not been included in the list of your trusted certificates.Its a .store file. Upon debugging in Eclipse its x509 cert upon inspection.

How do i include it in list of trusted certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Signer's identity is unknown because it has not been included in the list of your trusted certificates` message is from adobe acrobat or from reader. To solve the problem you've to include the issuer `CA` of your certificate to acrobat configuration.

You can do the following next steps:

Validate the signature from acrobat and then when adobe says that is invalid  access to the signature properties. On the new window select `signer` tab and click on <kbd>show certificate</kbd> button then you see the certificate validation path. Now you have to select the issuer `CA` certificate and in the `trust` tab click on <kbd>Add to Trusted identities...</kbd> button, then you can validate the signature again and this time must be valid.

If for test purpose you're signing with a selfsigned certificate add directly the certificate to trusted identities instead of the `CA`.

Hope this helps,